# How to get address returned by formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, hyperlink

I have a sheet where the data shown is based on combobox selections. The values are calculated using a formula like this:

```
INDEX(INDIRECT($Q61),SUMPRODUCT((INDIRECT($O$5)=$B$1)*(INDIRECT($O$6)=$B$2)*(INDIRECT($O$3)=$B$3)*(INDIRECT($O$7)=B$4)*ROW(INDIRECT($O$8)))-5),"")
```

Q61 is a range in a different sheet: 'Data'!$AO$6:$AO$104000
SUMPRODUCT matches four other criteria based on combobox selections.

The formula should calculate the row in the range and return a value. Is there a way in VBA to determine the address found by that formula.  It should be something like 'Data'!$AO$90.  I must get the address because I am looking for the hyperlink in that address.

The INDEX formula correctly returns the value in 'Data'!$AO$90.  I want to put back the hyperlink.

This is an image of the sheet.  Each value is calculated using an INDEX formula as shown above.  A few values should have hyperlinks.  I must get the original address in the 'Data'! sheet to put them back with VBA whenever the user makes a new selection.

[image]

Comment: You gan get Excel to show you the `row_num` being used by the `INDEX()`. Select the cell with the formula, and click on the word INDEX in the formula bar.  Click `row_num` in the dropdown and hit the `F9` key. There are illustrations in an answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1315726/excel-getting-false-when-the-value-is-in-the-row-array/1315832#1315832).

Comment: You can also use `=CELL("address",your_formula).

Answer (score 0):

From `'Data'!$AO$6:$AO$104000` range , you get the value in `'Data'!$AO$90` . That is how a standard index() functions do.

Since you just need the address of `'Data'!$AO$90` you can get it by bisecting the index() function you use to get it. The idea is.. since `index(<range>,<RowNumber>,<ColNumber>)`, and for this case let sat the  is 85. So the "address" you need is

```
= "'Data'!$AO$"&(<RowNumber>+5)
```

Have a try, hope that helps. ( :

Answer (score 0):

`INDEX()` can return a cell reference (address) instead of a value.

(That sounds like you would set a parameter and get either a value in the cell, or the cell's address. This, sadly, very sadly, is NOT so. What you have to do is to USE the function in a context that only makes sense if an address is returned, not the value in it. Excel will then do just that. It's when either way would make sense to it, and when only a value would make sense, that it defaults to returning a value.)

You can do this lots of ways. But the simplest is to use the `CELL()` function, asking for the address:

```
=CELL("address",INDEX(range,row,column))
```

This will return the exact cell address. The address is text, but unlike some such returns, `INDIRECT()` will recognize it nicely and return the value there. That would basically seem pointless! But it means pretty much any function should accept it directly so any use as text should be valid.

*(I know this is in the Comments, but since I want to expand on the subject, to explain it rather than just let a "mention" stand, and to connect it to some other "dots" in the Excel formula world, I am making this answer.)*

Contrast that with functions that do return text, or so it seems, but it is really an array constant from which the first element is selected for return. (So, what it is really handling is something like `{"a",2;"HH",298;} and so on. Having a clean return is much easier to handle as a feed into another function wrapped around the work to that point. Anyway... it's a clean return and that makes a difference.)

No need for offsets due to a range not anchoring in A1. It's the actual cell address, not something relative in the range. So it simplifies many, many things. Of course, sometimes you'd want those offsets, I suppose, but you can easily add them back in.

We used to achieve `FILTER()`-like results once upon a time with `INDEX()`-returned cell addresses leading to ranges of rows. Picture a set of data neatly arranged by date. (Entered that way, sorted, doesn't matter.) Use `INDEX/MATCH` to find the address of the first cell that has some date (2/15 perhaps). That gives the row needed and you know the first column used in the data (or can easily find out if it's dynamic or in a Named Range) so you can easily generate the first cell in the desired range that you are creating's address. Then use `INDEX/MATCH` for the next date (2/16 in this example) BUT using A NEAT TRICK:  use `INDEX()` to invert the lookup array using another NEAT TRICK (didn't have `SEQUENCE()` in the old days) to pass a declining array of values to it for the rows. This allowed `MATCH()` to use the match type "Greater than" so it finds the next highest date if not an exact match. That gives you an address that is one row too high so you get the row and subtract one. You know (or can easily find if...) the last column used so you have created the end address for the range of data that has the desired date.

The NEAT TRICKS:

```
=4-MATCH(H1+1,INDEX(G1:G3,4-ROW(1:3),),-1)
```

For the simple, 1 column, 3 row table G1:G3, you use `ROW()` in the usual way to create an array constant, `{1,2,3}` which is not helpful in and of itself, but if subtracted from a value one higher than the highest row in the function (3 is the highest row, so 4), one gets `{3,2,1}` and the table is presented in a reverse order which in my example is "descending" order, so you can use the "Greater than" match type in the `MATCH()` function. That gets the row in the upside-down table so you then subtract THAT from the same 4 to get the row in the "real" table. NEAT TRICKS, eh?

You have those two portions of a range and just put a ":" between the two halves of the formula a bit like so:

```
=INDEX(first half of the desired range address):INDEX(second half of the desired range address)
```

Just like that. Literally simply a colon between the two calculations, not even needing double quotes or ampersands.

`FILTER()` is obviously much to be preferred, but you can see how the feature is used. By placing the colon between formula halves, you make it completely clear to Excel that addresses are desired, not values, and it happily gives you addresses (references).

I was handicapped for years thinking I just didn't know a parameter, that the documentation and internet help on the subject was garbage for not telling me what tiny little thing I had to not be doing. (It was all garbage... really, you know... since it only was clear AFTER you already knew the "one tiny thing" it did no good whatsoever for me, so:  garbage. Kind of the ultimate "in crowd" thing.)

Once I realized it was never directly under our control and never would be, that there was no "one tiny thing" to know and do, it was all clear. This also applies to a surprisingly large number of other quixotic help in the Microsoft sources and on the internet. It can help you in far more things than just this.